# node and npm in iOS apps

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, node.js, npm

Whats the use of node and npm in iOS apps? In my interview I was asked to create an iOS app that uses node and npm package.

Can I make an application without them and somehow embed them later on,I am a noob in this area.

Please help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Did they mean for your iOS app to communicate with a remote node.js server?  Or for a node.js server to be on the iOS device?  There has to be more to the objective than just pile together disparate pieces of technology into the same app.

Comment: @jfriend00 i think the latter. but i don't know anything about this so i didn't quite understand what they meant.But whichever is easier

Comment: Then, you need some clarification on the objective.